# Function of bounded variation and integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let f belong to $C[a,b]$. Show that there is a function g that is of bounded variation on [a,b] for which $\int_a^bfdg=||f||_{max}$ and TV(f)=1.

This problem appears on page 162 of Royden's Real analysis. I have to say that I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that there is a point $t_0 \in [a,b]$ where $|f(t_0)| = \|f\|_{\max}$. If $t_0 \in (a,b]$, let $g=\chi_{[t_0,1]}$. Then $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dg(t)=f(t_0)$. Now multiply $g$ by a unimodular scalar $e^{i\theta}$ in order to arrange $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)d(e^{i\theta}g)(t)=|f(t_0)|=\|f\|_{\max}$. Clearly $V_{a}^{b}(e^{i\theta}g)=1$. A minor modification works if $t_0=a$.

Comment: I think I get the point, however, how to evaluate the integral? There is a breaking point and on two sides of the breaking point the integral should be 0. Am I right? Or I make some mistake?

Comment: @PeterLiu : The jump function serves as a legitimate delta function in this context. The evaluation is the value of the function at the jump times the jump. The variation is the magnitude of the jump. If you set up Riemann-Stieltjes sums, you'll see it.

Comment: I see. I do know how to use delta function, but it doesn't appear in that textbook. Do we have some other ways to avoid imposing delta function?

Comment: @PeterLiu : Don't bother with it. It's just a point-of-view, and it's more trouble than it's worth. :) You know how to evaluate the integral when there's a jump, and that's what counts.